# RegEx for separating number tail from any-character string?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am keen to find RegEx approach for my problem, for separating number tail from the any-character leading string. I have done work to similar issues with string processing, but I think RegEx might offer me less effort, and be usefull for future.

I have kinda complex strings with number at the end:

```
'TxAnt0Standard_deviation_peak_variation'

'MeasCfg5Seq1TxAnt2MaxDiff_phase2'

'MeasCfg6Seq1TxAnt0MinAmpl_error_ant10'
```

etc.

I need to separate the number tail from the rest:

`TxAnt0Standard_deviation_peak_variation'` and `''`

`'MeasCfg5Seq1TxAnt2MaxDiff_phase'` and `'2'`

`'MeasCfg6Seq1TxAnt0MinAmpl_error_ant'` and `'10'`

I found one example that uses re.match() method. And I am trying something like this:

```
     match = re.match(r"(.+)([0-9]*)", limitName, re.I)

        items=tuple()
        if match:
            items = match.groups()

        basis = items[0] #res: whole string
        tail =items[1] #res: ''
```

which in turn does not do the task, what I get ist the whole string, and an empty sting.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you post the required output that you are aiming for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
match = re.match(r"(.*\D)?(\d*)$", limitName)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vrviwz/1/). Note that `re.match` looks for a match at the start of the string, this is why I am not using the `^` anchor.

**Pattern details**

- `(.*\D)?` - an optional capturing group matching any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible up to the last non-digit char  followed with...
- `(\d*)` - Capturing group #2: any 0 or more digit
- `$` - end of string.

Digits are caseless, you need no `re.I` modifier.